My new ceiling fan's remote won’t connect to the transmitter when attached to the ceiling plate
We purchased a Fanimation ceiling fan which wouldn’t work. The company sent us a new receiver and remote but it still didn’t work. They then sent a whole new ceiling fan which works when the unit is dropped from the ceiling and the receiver is exposed. But when we reattach the unit to the ceiling the signal is lost. We have tried multiple codes but the problem remains. Is it possible to boost the signal or how else to get this to function properly? Without the remote working the fan will run but not the light and the fan needs to be turned on and off by the wall switch.

Fanimation has lots of fans. What's the model number of yours?

Is there an antenna on the transmitter that needs to be sticking out of the ceiling box?  Is it?

We tried having the wire stick out, no luck. But we just now found a solution, purchased a Honeywell universal ceiling fan and light control remote. It works! We need to stand directly under the unit for it to be successful but that’s an ok trade off. Thanks for your help!
